# How to format number in mootools number.format()

Tags: javascript, numbers, mootools

I need format number `(123456)` as `123 456`

I used:

```
(123456).format({groups: ' '}) //result 123,456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [`group`](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Number.Format) not `groups`.

```
console.log( (123456789).format({
    group: " "
}) );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAGPE/)